# Fullpage.js with jQuery Cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js, jcycle

im working on something that I need to use both Fullpage.js at jQuery Cycle at the same time. Now what I want to happen is to have multiple Fullpage that would slide if I click the navigation with jCycle. My javascript codes goes like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#firstpage').fullpage({
            sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
            scrollingSpeed: 1000
        });

        var titles = ['FirstPage','SecondPage'];
        $('#list') 
            .before('<div id="nav">') 
            .cycle({ 
                fx:     'scrollRight', 
                speed:  'fast', 
                timeout: 0, 
                pager:  '#nav',
                pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index) {
                    return '<a href="#">' + titles[index] + '</a>';
                }
            });
    });
```

and my html

```
<div id="list">
<div>
        <div id="firstpage">
            <div class="section " id="section0">
                <img src="imgs/fullPage.png" alt="fullPage" />
            </div>
            <div class="section" id="section1">
            </div>
            <div class="section" id="section2">
                <div class="intro">
                    <img src="imgs/example2.png" alt="example" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section" id="section3">
                <div class="intro"></div>
                <img src="imgs/tablets.png" alt="tablets" />
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div>
        <div id="secondpage">
            <div class="section" id="section4">
                <img src="imgs/fullPage.png" alt="fullPage" />
            </div>
            <div class="section" id="section5">
            </div>
            <div class="section" id="section6">
                    <img src="imgs/example2.png" alt="example" />
            </div>
        </div>  
</div>
```

The firstpage is properly working but when is try to navigate for the secondpage scrolling is no longer working, but when I try to add something like this in the javascript, scrolling on both page is not working.

```
$('#secondpage').fullpage({
            sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
            scrollingSpeed: 1000
        });
```

Help me guys, thanks in advance..

Comment: I think it will work with $('#list').fullpage({ }); for both he cases!

Comment: I tried it, its no good. thanks btw.

Comment: see it's working http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/6SQhb/303/

Comment: but i want to have another page, its working on single page or single fullpage, but when i try to have two fullpage, its no longer working..

Comment: why you want to use two full pages, not able to work with sections?

Comment: I want to navigate multiple pages on one page. I just want to scrollright whenever the user click the navigation and display it on the same page.

Comment: that is achieved through sections within particualr DIV using singlle fullpage. http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

Comment: You probably need to make use of some Cycle callback such as `after` and in there destroy the previous instance of fullpage.js to create another one. But of course, I haven't tried it and I'm not 100% sure it would work.